# Call structure field from a string variable

Tags: matlab, data-structures, struct

As output of some previous code, I get a structure with a certain amount of fields, whose amount can change. I want  to call the last one of them, but I do not know what I should use to call a field name from a dynamic variable, since according to [this page](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html) it seems I should use round brackets, but it apparently does not work, since if I run this code:

```
A = rand(3,1);
B = rand(4,1);
C = rand(2,1);
S = struct('field1',A,'field2',B,'field3',C);
names = fieldnames(S);
S.(names(end));
```

I get this error:

```
Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.
```

Why does it now work and what should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fieldnames function actually returns a cell.
When you use smooth parentheses '(',')' such as in *names(end)*, you actually gets a cell of size 1x1 which contains the string 'field3':

```
class(names(end))
ans = cell
```

In your case you should use curly braces for accessing the data in order to get the string representation of your field. In other words, use the following syntax:

```
S.(names{end})
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for the clear explaination.